# Go build fails when building docker image

Tags: docker, go

I'm a little new to golang and I'm still trying to get my head around the difference between `go run main.go` and `go build [-o] main.go`.

I've build a little gin app to try out locally with docker and kubernetes.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {

    r := gin.Default()

    r.GET("/healthz", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "")
    })

    r.GET("/readinez", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "")
    })

    r.Run() // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
}
```

The app runs perfectly fine with `go run main.go`.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:latest
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN go build -o main .
CMD ["/app/main"]
```

It fails:

[image]

It is definitely in there and it also works when I `go run main.go`. What is the difference to build?

I'm not sure what to do here. Coming from a node background. This does drive a noobie somewhat mad... Sure there is an easy solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program succeeds on your machine because you probably have the gin package installed. You can't assume a container will have it, and should install it explicitly.  Just add the following line to your dockerfile before the `go build` line:

```
RUN go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin
```

Comment: Thx that worked. How can one set this up more efficiently in the go world? Its not really practical to add every package manually to docker. Any good ideas articles/tutorials I could read?

Comment: One way is to vendor the gin-gonic package. Basicly means to copy the package over to your folder as a dependency. Please do look at dep and glide which should be the succesors of govendoring.

Comment: Incidentally, you can just run a naked `go get` to pull all dependencies.  That said, you (OP) may want to look into vendoring (https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2015/vendor-folder).  It solves both this issue and problems that arise from differing dependency versions. (Edit: damn, beat me to it, Hace)

Answer (score 0):

It may have failed because you used gin, and the library cannot be found inside the container. Try to use glide or godep to vendoring third party library.

Answer (score 0):

```
go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin
```

Then it should work.